# How to add META-INF/context.xml in lein-ring uberwar

Tags: tomcat, clojure, leiningen, ring

When generating an uberwar with `lein-ring`, I'm able to add resources to the class path using the `:resource-paths` key in the root of my `project.clj`. Any resources added this way appear under `/WEB-INF/classes/`

Due to legacy reasons, I need to provide a `context.xml` under `META-INF` at the root of the .war file (interpreted as a zip).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these sorts of purposes, `lein-ring` provides a `:war-resources-path` (optionally `:war-resource-paths`) key to be set at the root of your `project.clj`.

Any files under the directory (or directories) specified as such, will be copied directly into your .war file.

As such, place a folder in your project (I used `/war-root`) that contains `META-INF/context.xml` as you expect it to be.